# Convert C# to Python using AES/CBC/NoPadding

Tags: c#, python, encryption, aes

I'm trying to convert this C# code to Python (2.7). The problem is that the result of the decryption is wrong with the python code. IV and key is correct.

I found many subjects that talk about Python and C# but i didn't found an answer.

**C# encryption:**

```cs
class Tracer
{
    private static readonly int BlockBitSize = 128;
    private static readonly int KeyBitSize = 256;

    internal static byte[] In(byte[] plainBytes, byte[] uid)
    {
        using (var sha = new SHA512Managed())
        {
            var hash = sha.ComputeHash(uid);
            return In(plainBytes, hash.Skip(32).Take(32).ToArray(), hash.Take(16).ToArray());
        }
    }

    internal static byte[] In(byte[] plainBytes, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        if (key == null || key.Length != KeyBitSize / 8)
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Key needs to be {0} bit!", KeyBitSize), "key");
        if (iv == null || iv.Length != BlockBitSize / 8)
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("IV needs to be {0} bit!", BlockBitSize), "iv");

        using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
        {
            aes.KeySize = KeyBitSize;
            aes.BlockSize = BlockBitSize;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

            using (ICryptoTransform encrypter = aes.CreateEncryptor(key, iv))
                using (MemoryStream cipherStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(cipherStream, encrypter, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cryptoStream.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
                        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                    }
                    return cipherStream.ToArray();
                }
        }
    }

    internal static byte[] Out(byte[] cipherBytes, byte[] uid)
    {
        using (var sha = new SHA512Managed())
        {
            var hash = sha.ComputeHash(uid);
            return Out(cipherBytes, hash.Skip(32).Take(32).ToArray(), hash.Take(16).ToArray());
        }
    }

    internal static byte[] Out(byte[] cipherBytes, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        if (key == null || key.Length != KeyBitSize / 8)
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Key needs to be {0} bit!", KeyBitSize), "key");
        if (iv == null || iv.Length != BlockBitSize / 8)
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("IV needs to be {0} bit!", BlockBitSize), "iv");

        using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
        {
            aes.KeySize = KeyBitSize;
            aes.BlockSize = BlockBitSize;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

            using (ICryptoTransform decrypter = aes.CreateDecryptor(key, iv))
                using (MemoryStream plainStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var decrypterStream = new CryptoStream(plainStream, decrypter, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(decrypterStream))
                        {
                            //Decrypt Cipher Text from Message
                            binaryWriter.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                        }
                    //Return Plain Text
                    return plainStream.ToArray();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**Python decryption**

```python
def AESdecrypt(ciphertext, UID):

    from Crypto.Cipher import AES

    digest = hashlib.sha512(UID).hexdigest()

    iv = BitArray(hex=digest[:32])

    key = BitArray(hex=digest[64:128])

    block40Str = BitArray(hex=ciphertext[1].encode('hex'))

    cipherSpec = AES.new(key.bytes, AES.MODE_CBC, iv.bytes)
    plaintextWithPadding = cipherSpec.decrypt(block40Str.bytes)
```

Note : Sorry for my english

Thanks for your help !

EDIT : AES decryption in Python return 64 characters, that is wrong. The original plaintext is 32.

EDIT2: Python code updated. The decrypt function return now 32 characters, but still doing wrong

Comment: I don't know python but `hexdigest` looks like it returns a string representation of the data rather than the binary values which C# uses, so python may be using the (character) bytes from the hexadecimal string rather than the actual bytes.

Comment: The python version also converts ciphertext[1] to hex, which may be just one byte if ciphertext is a string.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @AlexK. i tried to give the actual bytes not converted in string, but the decrypt aes fonction says that the lenght is not equal to a multiple of 16.

Comment: @JanneKarila. i optain a string representation of the ciphertext, because the aes function need a string. Perhaps I don't understand, I don't have much knowledge in this area, do you have exemple to fix it ? Thanks

Comment: The usual representation of binary data is `bytes` in Python 3 and `str`  in Python 2.

Comment: I don't get it, why not just use `digest()`? Why is your IV 16 hex characters instead of 32? Where is your digest in your C# code? Why don't you close your streams before retrieving the plaintext or ciphertext? Are you just trying things in some random fashion? Because crypto will happily provide you with random results.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-owlstead digest return a format like "\x05\x06" and i need only "0506" to have iv and key with the correct lenght in string format. IV must be 16 because the ciphertext must be 16 lenght. The C# enryption/decryption work, he don't provide random results. No, i don't try fashion random things for my plesure, and if I do, i'm there to get help. ;-)

Comment: @JanneKarila I think the problem is there, I'm looking for fix

Comment: "\x05\x06" is a string of two characters that have the hex values of 05 and 06.

Comment: Yes, but if i pass this format : "\x05\x06", the function return an error of string length, because it concider the \x as characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The digest used to generate the key and the iv was generated with the correct data but in string. Conversely, C# generate the digest with a ByteArray of the data. Thanks to the [BitArray Python library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) , i solve my problem :

**New Python code :**

```
def AESdecrypt(ciphertext, UID):

    from Crypto.Cipher import AES

    UIDBytes = BitArray(hex=UID)
    digest = hashlib.sha512(UIDBytes.bytes).hexdigest()

    iv = BitArray(hex=digest[:32])

    key = BitArray(hex=digest[64:128])

    cipherSpec = AES.new(key.bytes, AES.MODE_CBC, iv.bytes)
    plaintextWithoutPadding = cipherSpec.decrypt(ciphertext[1])
```